# Prevent misspelled variables passed to Ansible roles

Tags: ansible

I'm looking for strategies to mitigate silent errors related to misspelled or otherwise mistyped variables being passed to Ansible roles.

So for example, I have a role with a defaults/main.yml:

```
foo_version: "1.0"
```

Within the tasks/main.yml:

```
- get_url:
    url: "https://foo.com/foo-{{ foo_version }}.tar.gz"
    dest: /tmp/
```

Now in my main playbook, if I do this, it will install the default version, 1.0:

```
- include_role: name=foo
```

If I do this, it will install version 2.0:

```
- include_role: name=foo
  vars:
    foo_version: "2.0"
```

So far so good. But if I do this by accident, it will install 1.0 without my realizing it:

```
- include_role: name=foo
  vars:
    fooo_version: "2.0"
```

The only "solution" I've thought of is to remove the defaults/main.yml, in which case it would fail in the last case because `foo_version` would remain undefined. But then I can't take advantage of the benefits of having defaults.

Are there other solutions? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> Q: " Prevent misspelled variables passed to Ansible roles ... remove the defaults/main.yml, ... But then I can't take advantage of the benefits of having defaults. Are there other solutions?

A: Yes. Tell *include_role* to read other file [*defaults_from*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/include_role_module.html#parameters). Fit the content of this file to your needs. For example

```
- include_role:
    name: foo
    defaults_from: main_special.yml
  vars:
    fooo_version: "2.0"
```

Comment: I believe this suffers from the same problems. If I loaded defaults from `main_special.yml` using `defaults_from`, and then specified `fooo_version: "2.0"` expecting it to override the default software version, I'm going to silently have problems.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with what I think is a pretty good solution.

First, it requires the addition of this to each role:

```
- assert:
    that: "{{ item.key }} is defined"
    fail_msg: "Attempted to override an unknown variable: {{ item.key }}"
    quiet: yes
  loop: "{{ q('dict', override) }}"

- set_fact: { "{{ item.key }}":"{{ item.value }}" }
  loop: "{{ q('dict', override) }}"
```

I added those two tasks to a file, `override.yml` within `ansible/tasks/`, and then used `include_tasks` to dynamically include that file only when `override` is actually defined:

```
- include_tasks: "tasks/override.yml"
  when: override is defined
```

Second, it requires that when you override defaults with `import_role` that you do the following:

```
- include_role:
    name: foo
  vars:
    override:
      fooo_version: "2.0"
```

The first block of code now loops through the passed `override` dictionary, and verifies that each key already is defined as a variable. So in the above example, the assert would fail because `fooo_version` is not defined. It then loops through the `override` dictionary a second time and uses `set_fact` to set the value of each key:val pair in the dictionary.